# Finding all personal sites in my site collection through REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, site-collection, mysite

I want to know if there is any way I can get the entire list of My Sites (personal sites) with in the My Site collection for a tenant.

So I'm looking for all sites under

```
https://{tenantName}-my.sharepoint.com
```

site collection for a tenant. I have come across various answers saying I could do a search query on **STS_Site** but please not that I am using App Only Token and that doesn't work for App Only Access Token (i.e, for *Client Credentials Flow*)

Isn't there any other way through REST API that I can get this list?

```
https://{tenantName}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/abc_domain_com
https://{tenantName}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/pqr_domain_com
https://{tenantName}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xyz_domain_com
...
```

I was hoping this would give me the sites under My Site Collection

```
https://{tenantName}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/web/webs
```

but I get the following

```
{
    "d": {
    "results": []
    }
}
```

Much appreciated!

**PS:** I even tried *Authorization Code Grant Flow* to get the access token and did a search query for *STS_Site* content type, but it doesn't return me the entire list, just a subset! The user I made the search query with is the *Global Admin* so this info should be entirely available but it isn't.
The *Authorization Code Grant Flow* is not of much use to me because of certain limitations(one of them is the visibility of sites like above and some others). So I am more interested in finding a solution using *Client Credentials Flow* (App Only Access Token)

Is there a way?

Comment: Personal sites are all different site collections by themselves, so you can't get them using `webs`.

Comment: Yes indeed. But isn't there any way to get these list of sites?

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the REST API and so may not meet your needs but this is easy to do with the PowerShell module for o365 Sharepoint ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps )

Install and connect to SPO via Powershell and then

```
$AllSites = Get-SPOSite -IncludePersonalSite:$true -Limit All
$AllSites | ? Url -LIKE "*/personal/*"
```